# Name of a live-action Saturday morning show from the '70s, involving bigfoot/caveman?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a 30-minute Saturday morning show growing up in the US that involved something living in the hills outside of a town. It was either a bigfoot or a caveman (can't remember). The creature was friends with a kid from the town, who would make him come help by blowing a horn or calling for him.

Sorry for how vague this is, but it has bugged me for years. I definitely know that I watched it in the 1979-1980 timeframe, but it might have been produced earlier. I have found nothing when searching for it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is ***[Bigfoot and Wildboy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0147751/)*** (1977-1979).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot_and_Wildboy):

> *Bigfoot and Wildboy* was a live action children's television series on ABC. It began in 1977 as a part of The Krofft Supershow on Saturday mornings. Each episode was 15 minutes long, with cliffhanger endings resolved the following week. It became its own series in 1979 with twelve 30-minute episodes. There were a total of 28 episodes produced.
>
> The series was heavily influenced by the two-part Bigfoot episodes of *The Six Million Dollar Man*, from the super-powered Bigfoot character to “bionic” sound effects used for Bigfoot running and leaping and the use of slow motion photography for action scenes such as throwing a giant object or uprooting a large metal fence post.

From IMDB:

> Children's series about Wildboy, an orphan who was raised in the wilderness of the Pacific Northwest by the legendary Sasquatch. Wildboy and Bigfoot roamed the countryside stomping out pollution, capturing diabolical villains, and rescuing those in distress.

In the episode below, you can see a girl in a small town calling for Bigfoot's help, which prompts him to come running down from the hills. In other episodes, Wildboy is the one who calls for him.

Comment: That is definitely it. I remember the slow motion run of bigfoot.

Comment: Where did they find a wookie in the wild west?

Comment: Of course it was part of the psychedelic Krofft Supershow   :)